# difference between the first value and the last values of the each days

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table, I have several measures per day

```
29011   2012-12-28 09:00:00
28701   2012-12-28 10:00:00
28830   2012-12-28 11:00:00
28353   2012-12-28 12:00:00
28642   2012-12-28 13:00:00
28583   2012-12-28 14:00:00
28800   2012-12-29 09:00:00
28751   2012-12-29 10:00:00
28670   2012-12-29 11:00:00
28621   2012-12-29 12:00:00
28599   2012-12-29 13:00:00
28278   2012-12-29 14:00:00
```

How can I obtain the **difference** between **the first last values of the each days** ?

I would like a result like this :

```
428 2012-12-28
522 2012-12-29
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT (MAX(volume) - MIN(volume)),DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp), '%Y-%m-%d') date FROM tank
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp), '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY tstamp
```

But it doesn't take the first and last measures, but the min and max.

Comment: you should have an `AUTO_INCREMENTED` column that identifies the sequence of the records.

Comment: You need some way to identify the order of the records, in order to get the first and last.

Comment: You would need something like FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE() which are analytical functions, but not supported by MySQL natively.
You can try to use the following approach http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Comment: @JW : The date is in fact a DATE field. The data above are already sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subselect to get the min and max timestamps for the day, then join the result of that against the origin table twice, once for the min and once for the max to get the volumes. Then calculate:-

```
SELECT Sub1.JustDate, (b.volume - a.volume) AS VolumeDifference
FROM (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS JustDate, MIN(tstamp) AS MinTimeStamp, MAX(tstamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
FROM tank
GROUP BY JustDate) Sub1
INNER JOIN tank a ON Sub1.MinTimeStamp = a.tstamp
INNER JOIN tank b ON Sub1.MaxTimeStamp = b.tstamp
```

This is assuming they are real unix timestamps, and not just a CCYYMMDD date with no way to tell which is the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with MySQL 8, the optimal approach would involve using the [`FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/11/07/dont-miss-out-on-awesome-sql-power-with-first_value-last_value-lead-and-lag/)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  first_value(volume) OVER w - last_value(volume) OVER w AS diff,
  CAST(tstamp AS DATE) AS date
FROM tank
WINDOW w AS (
  PARTITION BY CAST(tstamp AS DATE) 
  ORDER BY tstamp
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
ORDER BY CAST(tstamp AS DATE)
```

For more details, refer to the manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_last-value

Answer (score 1):

Since date string is lexicographically sortable, just add the two columns together like:

```
"2012-12-28 09:00:00_29011"
```

In a subselect and call min() and max() on this generated column.
Then you can separate the _number part to get your first and last numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this postgres, and it is working

```
select (maxvalue1-minalue1) as date, time from(
select min(id) as minalue1, max(id) as maxvalue1, time::Date from master_booking group by time::date
) data
```

Check it out.

Comment: Correct, but he doesn't want MIN and MAX of each groups, but rather an equivalent to the analytical functions FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

First and Last are relative values in this case, since there is nothing that says which of these values:

```
29011   2012-12-28
28701   2012-12-28
28830   2012-12-28
28353   2012-12-28
28642   2012-12-28
28583   2012-12-28
```

was the first or the last. You could add an auto_increment ID to the table, so that you can sort on that, or you can change the date to a datetime field, so you can sort on datetime.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> SELECT ( max(volume) keep(dense_rank last order by to_char(tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')) - min(volume) keep(dense_rank last order by to_char(tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')) ) difference, to_char(tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD') date FROM tank
>   GROUP BY to_char(tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')
>   ORDER BY to_char(tstamp,'YYYY-MM-DD')